# how to set wxpython AuiPaneInfo background color?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I want to change WxPython GUI AuiPaneInfo() background color, but there is no resources mention that. Hope someone can give me a solution.

Thanks

Class EditorNotebook:

```
class EditorNotebook(aui.AuiNotebook):
def __init__(self, parent):
    agwStyle = aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE | \
               aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ALL_TABS | \
               aui.AUI_NB_SMART_TABS | \
               aui.AUI_NB_TAB_FLOAT | \
               aui.AUI_NB_WINDOWLIST_BUTTON
    aui.AuiNotebook.__init__(self, parent, agwStyle=agwStyle)
    self.SetBackgroundColour(core.Client.ThemeBackgroundColor)
    self.pageOpenOrder = []

    self.Bind(aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_UP, self.OnTabRightUp)
    self.Bind(aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_DCLICK, self.OnTabDClick)
    self.Bind(aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CLOSE, self.OnPageClose)
```

Part of panel generate code:

```
    self.TabMgr = EditorNotebook(self)
    self.TabMgr.SetArtProvider(aui.VC71TabArt())
    self.TabMgrPaneInfo = aui.AuiPaneInfo().Center().Layer(1) \
        .MaximizeButton().MinimizeButton().Caption(" ") \
        .CloseButton(False).BestSize2(400, 600).MinSize(100, 100)
    self.WinMgr.AddPane1(self.TabMgr, self.TabMgrPaneInfo)

    core.Client.setTabMgr(self.TabMgr)
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem so. I suggest that you put something in there, that you can set the background colour of, like a panel. This is the perfect example of when a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example would be appropriate. 1. in creating it, there is a high probability that you would find an answer yourself and 2, failing that, the rest of us could play with it, to find a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I hope i can do it, but this project is really big, and i cannot pull it out. But i will remember you suggestion if i have other question need help. Thanks